# Where did the datatypes get their name from?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, types, sqldatatypes

Why is a bit, called a bit. Why is a 8-bits a Byte? What made people call a 16-bits a Word, and so on. Where and why did their alias come about?

I would love other people to include things like basic [ASM](http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/AoA/Windows/HTML/DataRepresentationa2.html) types, then branch out to [C/C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/) and move on to [SQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-types.html) and the like's datatypes.

1. 1-Bit

   1. [Bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit) - **b**inary Un**it**
   2. Bool - Named after the inventor of boolen logic George [Boole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Boole).
2. 4-Bits

   1. Nibble - Half the size of bite/byte.
3. 8-Bits

   1. Byte - [Coined from "bite" but respelled to avoid accidental mutation to "bit"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte).
   2. Char
   3. Octet - [Is a grouping of eight bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_%28computing%29), [from the Latin "octo" meaning "eight".](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/October)
4. 16-Bits

   1. Word (unsigned integer)
   2. short (signed integer)
5. 32-Bits

   1. Double Word
   2. int (signed integers)
   3. unsigned (unsigned integer)
   4. float (4-byte float)

Comment: Note that in C++ the number of bits a data-type occupies is implementation dependent. A char could for instance be 7 bits.

Comment: AFAIK a byte is the underlying machine's native small data type. There are machines that don't have 8bit bytes.

Comment: The same could be said of floats not always taking up 32 bits. But I'm just trying to get the basic data types down so I could understand why they are named in such a way. I'm hoping that people, once they understand the foundation of the datatype name will better understand how to use it.

Comment: @Space: No. char must be at least 8 bits. Btw, there are machines with char == ... == long == 32bit.

Comment: @ybungalobill: I stand corrected. Thanks!

Comment: @ybungalobill: I though `short` must be smaller than `long` and `char` should be smaller than or equal to `short`? Do I remember this wrong?

Comment: @sbi, see my point in asking this question now? It's in sane how basic this is, but it's also surprising how many people don't have a full grasp on the subject.

Comment: @Mark: No, actually I don't see your point. What has "Where did the data types get their names from?" to do with the details of restrictions on C's built-in integer types?

Comment: @sbi, because surly it would be intrinsic to it's name. Long can not be less then short. Short can not be greater then long. It confounds the mind, and the English language to use these terms in such a was that is simply not accurate for their meaning.

Comment: @sbi: standard requires `1 =: sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)`. They all may be equal. to be fair I can't find right now where the minimal sizes are specified.

Comment: The sizes you specify are wrong in a lot of languages and on a lot of hardware. For example, double word is specific to x86 (most 32-bit CPU's just define a word to be 32 bits)

Comment: "Historically, a byte was the number of bits (typically 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, or 16) used to encode a single character of text in a computer" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wikipedia is your friend:

- [bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit)
- [nibble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble)
- [byte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte)
- "char" is just short for "character"
- "short" is an alias for "short int"
- [word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computing) "is the native or most efficient size the CPU can handle" (thanks to [Tony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/410767/tony) for pointing that out).
- "int" is short for "integer". The size is undefined (can be 16, 32 or 64 bits).
- "float" is short for "floating point number"
- "double" is short for "double precision floating point number"

Comment: I think this is proof that you can ask a stupid question and get an intelligent answer on here. Thank you @Aaron.

Comment: I understand "word" to be the native or most efficient size the CPU can handle - an untyped amount of memory.  This may be compared and contrasted to int, which though numeric was also initially meant to be sized based on maximum utility (range) without compromising efficiency, but given CPUs sometimes have a couple equally efficient sizes, and certain restrictions and expectations have been put on int (esp. given long, long long), the two may actually differ in size.  not necessarily the smallest.  Anything to support your assertion?  I can cite http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computing)

Comment: @Tony, agreed. I'd like to see a source for this as well. Quoting Donald Knuth would work, if he has written about it. I understand that word is used to denote the smallest addressable unit of data by a CPU, but why is it called a word then? Is it because humans communicate in words and letters (bits) make up those words. I'm looking for the foundation of these names.

Comment: @Mark: "agreed... word...denote[s] the smallest" <-- that's exactly what I said it wasn't! :-).  I can only guess reasons: a binary-digit (bit) is rarely meaningful independent of other things around it (unless it's a boolean, but even then you often have to extract, mask and/or shift the _right_ bit into a convenient word-sized register).  But words are often numerically meaningful at the problem-domain level: big enough for the range of numbers in most common use - discrete at a meaning level - like a human-language _word_, vs. a syllable that can't be interpreted independently.

Comment: @Mark: a word isn't the smallest addressable unit. (That's usually a byte). If you want a counterexample, the x86 CPU you're using right now defines a word to be 16 bits wide, but the smallest addressable unit is still a 8-bit byte (or an octet).

Comment: @Mark Tomlin: There are no stupid questions, only stupid answers. If a toddler asks "What is 1+1?" is that stupid? :-)

Answer (score 3):

One that Aaron forgot was Bool: This goes back to the logician [Boole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Boole), who is attributed the invention of "boolean" logic.

Answer (score 2):

- A `bit` is a binary digit.
- A float should be clear (floating point semantics)

The rest, I could only guess

Comment: So it's called a `bit` because it's a `b`inary dig`it`?

Comment: I always thought it was `bi`nary digi`t` ;)

Answer (score 1):

I always thought 8 bits is called Octet, you live and learn. ;)

Comment: Is'nt it telecom people that call bytes octets?

Comment: @Jdv, Would octet not be the most correct name for it? And that brings us around to IP address what use 4 bytes (actually called, octets in this case) to make up an IP address.

Comment: @jdv: the french seem to be doing it a lot.

Comment: @snemarch, so it's a cultural thing? Does that mean the inventor of the IP address was French?

Comment: @Mark: probably also differs wrt. field of work - and my comment on the frenchies is based entirely on empirical observation of forums, mailing-lists and various pieces of software :)

Comment: An octet is an unambiguous term for an ordered set of 8 bits.  A byte is the smallest addressable unit on a computer which is almost always also 8 bits nowadays.  In network protocols, octet is used in order to be completely unambiguous because you are by definition not talking about a specific computer architecture.  For instance, if you defined an IP address as 4 bytes instead of 4 octets, a PDP 10 systems programmer would write you a network stack with 36 bit IP addresses.

Comment: Yeah, octet is the most "proper" name for a 8-bit unit. A byte is *usually* the same size, so most people conflate the two, but if you want to be specific, a byte is the smallest addressable unit (which is *usually* 8 bits on modern hardware), and an octet is a group of 8 bits. So in the end the size is usually the same, but they're derived differently

Comment: Keep in mind; In C(the standard), a byte is the char data type. However, in C , a byte need not be 8 bits, it's CHAR_BIT bits.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you may ask:
Why is m called as meter? Why is 1km represented by 1000m?

Tought question... Think it in simple way. Don't get yourself into tense.

Comment: Why is the scientific unit for measuring a meter `m`? Because, m is the first letter of meter, and m was not resurved by any other unit of measure. Kilo, (symbol 'k' lowercase) is a unit prefix in the metric system denoting one thousand.

Answer (score 0):

Your convention of short/int/long/word/dword for signed is not just an x86-ism; it's a Windows-ism (SHORT/LONG/WORD/DWORD). I don't see why Windows programmers like them so much when the standard (u)int*N*_t types are more clear to pretty much everyone.

I don't *think* x86 naturally comes with "word" and "double word"; registers are al,ah (8-bit), ax (16-bit), eax (32-bit). I forget how you specify the size of a memory-memory move, though.

M68K instructions have .b (byte), .w (word), and .l (long) suffixes. No double/quad-word IIRC.

ARM has ldb (byte), ldh (halfword), ldr (register).

PPC has byte, halfword, word, and doubleword IIRC.

In general, it's pretty meaningless to talk about "word size", since it's *highly* architecture-dependent, and even then it tends to change (I doubt that modern x86 implements 16-bit arithmetic any faster than 32-bit arithmetic).

Then there's also the "pointer size" definition, but amd64 only has 48-bit virtual addresses (the top 17 bits are supposed to be all 1 or all 0).

Comment: I don't know why some one downed voted you, because I found this quite insightful. So +1 to you.